# Last time of Isha and Tahajjud prayer

Tags: prayer-timings, tahajjud, makruh

I recently saw an answer for the last time of isha prayer and it says it's until fazr begins. It also says it is makruh(disliked act) to pray after midnight. Then i saw last time for tahajjud prayer and benefits of that and came to know the best time is the last 1/7th of the whole night.

**Now how can i do that as according to another information we should pray witr after tahajjud.**

*Isn't my witr would be makruh(disliked act)!!*

Please shed some light in context of Hadith and Quran.

Comment: "Midnight" is certainly a misinterpretation as the relevant hadith means the "middle of the night" (in hours at your location). This might be around midnight in the winter or after midnight in the summer.

Comment: Well that could be my mistake and ignorance of differences between two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything that claims that it is makruh to pray after midnight in general; to the best of my knowledge, the ruling you're referring to is specifically for the Isha prayer itself, and that it is makruh to delay that until after midnight.

Both Tahajjud and Witr are separate prayers for which that would not apply.

Answer (score 0):

For the Isha prayer, some people may regard it as makruh and some may not regard it as permissible at all. (read  https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/10125)

I have not seen anything about the ending of tahajjud prayer being in the last 1/7 of the night. Some websites have said that tahajjud ends when fajr begins.

Some scholars have said that the time for witr ends when dawn starts so I do not know how your witr would be makruh.
 “Pray Witr before morning comes.” Narrated by Muslim, 754. 
Muslim narrated from Ibn ‘Umar (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Hasten to pray witr before dawn.”
 Muslim narrated (752) that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Witr is one rak’ah at the end of the night.” 
Al-Tirmidhi narrated (469) from Ibn ‘Umar (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “When dawn comes, all the night prayers and Witr are over, so pray Witr before dawn comes.” Classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi. Also:
Al-Bukhaari (472) and Muslim (749) narrated that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The night prayers are two (rak’ahs) by two, then when you think that morning (dawn) is about to begin, pray one (rak’ah) and it will make what you have prayed Witr (odd-numbered).”

Comment: Actually i thought witr is counted as an isha prayer. Now i know that's not the case. And i read in islam q&a that more the time passes better are the rewards in case of tahajjud. There mentioned it's better to pray in 6/7th of the night time.

Comment: Yes me too. I was taught it was 4 sunnah then 4 fard then 2 sunnah then 2 nafl then 3 witr then 2 nafl. Whatever time is better to pray tahajjud just try to do what is best.